# Iterate over Pyspark array elements and within elements itself using loop twice

Tags: python, arrays, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a housing dataset in which I have both categorical and numerical variables. Out of this dataset I created another dataset of numeric_attributes only in which I have numeric_attributes in an array.
Dataset - Array values.
**Numeric_attributes
[No. of bedrooms, Price, Age]**

Now I want to loop over Numeric_attributes array first and then inside each element to calculate mean of each numeric_attribute.

Dataset 1

```
Age Price Location
20  56000  ABC
30  58999  XYZ
```

Dataset 2 (Array in dataframe)

```
Numeric_attributes 
[Age, Price]
```

Desired output

```
Mean(Age)  Mean(Price)
25         57000
```

Current attempt

```
 def minimum_value(df2):
    min_value = lambda x: x.min()
    for a in df2.collect():
        for b in a.collect():
            min_udf = F.udf(lambda row: [min_value(x) for x in b])
            df2.withColumn('minimum_value', min_udf(F.col('Numerical_attributes').cast("array<int>")))
        return df2
```

Comment: All are pyspark dataframe

Comment: Welcome to SO, you are often best helped if you add some sample data and expected output as it prevents a lot of confusion regarding your question.

Comment: Hi @ScootCork, I have already added sample data.

Comment: is it possible to have the Dataset 2 to be a Python list, not dataframe?

Comment: No, it should be a dataframe in which we have an array. @pltc

Comment: @pltc No, it should be a dataframe, within dataframe we have array